# iOS Vision API resampling causing conflicting results,?

Tags: ios, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, coreml

I have an object detection model trained on images of 640x480 color images. The model is transferred to CoreML+Swift and runs fine when we test on the images acquired in the native resolution format from the original validation set.

when tested on the fresh set of images/selfies acquired on a higher resolution camera on the phone, the results are very strange. There are many more bounding boxes detected and strange areas are detected as objects of interest.

My understanding tells me that the image resampling in the vision api is introducing some artifacts that may be detected of Object of interest.

**Question**

1. how does the vision API in iOS perform resampling of images ?
2. On the deep learning side : Should a resampled image vs. a native resolution image give different results in the output of the model ?

Answer (score 0):

You provided little to no detail in your question, but here are all the ideas I have.

On the 'deep learning' side, changing the image dimension's will, of course, affect model performance. However, the image size you describe is probably enough for your tasks. Training a model at 'native' resolution for iOS front-facing cameras is a bad idea. It would take substantially longer to train for no better results (you would also have a hard time getting training data unless you upsampled). Also, different iOS devices have different front-facing resolutions. All in all, your 'resampling' is *fine* - this is a conversion problem.

iOS has several ways of resampling and scaling images. How are *you* setting the scaling? Do you apply an `imageCropAndScaleOption` to the instantiated request?

```
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { [weak self] request, error in
    self?.processClassifications(for: request, error: error)
})
request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .centerCrop
return request
```

How do you convert the model to coreML? Something along the lines of...

```
model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
        './models/best.h5', 
        input_names=['image'],
        output_names=['output'],
        image_input_names='image',
        image_scale=1/255.0
)
```

When doing this, ensure that the image representation (for the input) is correctly represented. You can easily verify by printing the model after the conversion.

Along those lines, are the channels in the trained model (`RGB`) the same as all the images you are evaluated, or perhaps is the model trained in reverse channels (`BGR`) and the input data from `AVFoundation` is in `RGB`?

If you provide more specific details about your model, what it does, how you convert it to CoreML, and how you evaluate it, I can update my answer. But please address the above first.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. You missed a small detail. We already have it trained on 640x480 resolution. At inference time, we see the issue. Second , regarding the conversion, I use image as input and checked in the xcode side. I use _centerCrop_ prior to running the image request handler. To explain more, it works fine when we use 640x480 resolution images ( instantiated camera instance at that res ) as input to the model. If take a much higher res image and feed it into VNimagerequesthandler, the output is very different. We suspect its the resampling diff.  Thoughts ?